# How does "would" work in a sentence: The best choice would be...?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, modal-verbs

In the sentence "the best choice would be...", what does "would" mean in the following sentence?

> Questioner: Is this sentence correct?
>   'Finished eating, we went to the zoo'.
>
> Answer: I'm afraid that is not correct. The phrase 'Finished eating' is a participle phrase with a passive meaning and you need an active meaning here. The best choice **would** be 'Having finished eating...'.

Answer (score 1):

*Would* is used to convey the [conditional mood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_mood). The conditional mood conveys some sort of dependency on a condition. A more obvious example:

> If I had any sense, I would come in out of the rain.

In this case, it is fine to say *The best choice is "Having finished eating ..."* as well. Using the conditional conveys a sense of *If you were to say this again, the best choice would be "Having finished eating ..."*

Conditionals are often used in a sense like this, to "soften" the statement a bit. [This](https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/conditional/) is a good short overview of various forms of the conditional.

Now, *would* doesn't always denote conditional mood. It is also the past tense of *will*:

> They asked me to work late tomorrow, and I won't (will not) do it.
>   They asked me to work late yesterday, and I wouldn't (would not) do it.

*Would* is also used in a past sense to convey being in the habit of doing something (similar to *used to*):

> When I lived in Poughkeepsie, I would/used to take a walk every morning at eight.

There are other meanings, and you can see more of them [here](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/would).

Comment: Thank you. But there is no conditional (if) in the above. The speaker directly uses "would". Could you explain? I'm a liltle confised.

Comment: Sure. The conditional (if) is implied. Again, saying "would" conveys the meaning "if you were to say this again..." This happens rather often. Another example: "I would think so" conveys less confidence in one's opinion than "I think so." The implication is "If I had to form an opinion, I would think so." (Since I don't have to form an opinion, I only "probably" think so.) Sometimes you have to look pretty hard to find the "if," especially if it's a common phrase such as this one. But it's usually still there.

Comment: Thanks BobRodes. In the above sentence, does 'would' convey less confidence?

Comment: @whitekrystal Yes, I think it does a bit. Although perhaps it's better explained as a device to make one sound less opinionated.

Comment: @whitekrystal "I would like to play outside" is considered a nice request by a child to go outside.  "I want to play outside" is considered demanding and insistent.  Both mean the same thing, but the tone is radically different between the two.

Comment: @whitekrystal As Neil says, and this is true also of adults. *I would like* is generally considered more polite than *I want*. And the reason is an implied *if*: *I would like you to do x, if you are willing to do it*, or simply *I would like it if you did x.* *I want you to do x* doesn't imply any concern for what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

According to Practical English Usage, 3rd edition, 436.4:

It makes questions, requests, and suggestions less direct. For example:
I though it would be nice to have a picnic.
Hi! I thought I'd come over and introduce myself. My name's Andy.

Also based on Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English, the entry for this word number 10 says:

" used to give your opinion about something when you are not very sure about it".

So in your sentence, I think, the word "would" is all about being less certain or less direct.